# Alternative to $("#id .class") syntax when needing to match multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I write something like the following:

```
$("#id .class").css("display", "none");
```

PhpStorm gives me a warning saying `Inefficient jQuery usage.`

I've read several question on here about this, as well as [this article](http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck/) which says using the `.find()` method speeds things up significantly.

So, I dutifully went through all of my code and changed lines like this:

```
$("#id .class").css("display", "none");
```

To this:

```
$("#id").find(".class").css("display", "none");
```

Unfortunately, it appears this only applies the chained functions (in this case, `.css()`) to the first matching element on the page. So when there are multiple elements with `.class` that need to be hidden, the new code only hides the first one.

Should I just revert back to the way I had it before, or is there a more efficient method that will work with multiple elements?

Comment: Check your code. Your understanding of `.find()` is not accurate.. check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j1zoy1xw/

Comment: You have multiple duplicated ids in your DOM, which is a different issue that you should fix.  `$('#id')` will only find the _first instance_ of `#id`, whereas `#id .class`, since CSS selectors work _bottom up_, finds all instances of `.class` that have a parent of `#id`, therefore it finds all the instances on your page that you are expecting.  IDs are supposed to be unique, so either fix that issue or just revert your selectors.  @karthikr -- Duplicate the top node and you'll be able to reproduce OP's issue

Comment: @zyklus What do you mean by duplicate the top node? IDs are meant to be unique in a document.

Comment: @karthikr - Yes, I know, but OPs actual issue is duplicated IDs

Comment: @zyklus You're right, the page I noticed this problem on outputs containers with the same ID. That's the problem.

Comment: @zyklus Would you like to make your comment an answer? I could just delete the question, but then if someone else makes my mistake they won't be able to find your answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple duplicated ids in your DOM, which is a different issue that you should fix.  `$('#id')` will only find the *first instance* of `#id`, whereas `#id .class`, since CSS selectors work *bottom up*, finds all instances of `.class` that have a parent of `#id`, therefore it finds all the instances on your page that you are expecting. IDs are supposed to be unique, so either fix that issue or just revert your selectors.